# Scraping a website with data hidden under "read more"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape reviews from Tripadvisor.com and I want to get the data under 'Read More' button of the site. Is there anyway to scrape this without using selenium?

So far this is the code that I used

```
resp = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com.ph/Hotel_Review-g8762949-d1085145-Reviews-El_Rio_y_Mar_Resort-San_Jose_Coron_Busuanga_Island_Palawan_Province_Mimaropa.html#REVIEWS') 
rsp_soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
rsp_soup.findAll(attrs={"class": "hotels-review-list-parts-ExpandableReview__reviewText--3oMkH"})
```

But it can't scrape contents under the 'Read more'

Comment: what is your code so far?

Answer (score 2):

Reviews are partialy revealed in html until you click on `read more` which actually do not make an Ajax call but updates page from data contained in `window.__WEB_CONTEXT__`. You can access this data by looking into a `<script>` tag in which it appears:

```
<script>
     window.__WEB_CONTEXT__={pageManifest:{"assets":["/components/dist/@ta/platform.polyfill.084d8cdf5f.js","/components/dist/runtime.56c5df2842.js", ....  }
</script>
```

Once you've got it, you and you could extract and process the data which is of JSON format. Here is the full code:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
resp = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com.ph/Hotel_Review-g8762949-d1085145-Reviews-El_Rio_y_Mar_Resort-San_Jose_Coron_Busuanga_Island_Palawan_Province_Mimaropa.html#REVIEWS') 

data = BeautifulSoup(resp.content).find('script', text = re.compile('window.__WEB_CONTEXT__')).text

#Some text processing to make the tag content a valid json
pageManifest = json.loads(data.replace('window.__WEB_CONTEXT__=','').replace('{pageManifest:', '{"pageManifest":')[:-1])


for x in pageManifest['pageManifest']['apolloCache']:
    try:
        reviews = x['result']['locations'][0]['reviewList']['reviews']       
    except:
        pass

print([x['text'] for x in reviews])
```

**Output**

```
['Do arrange for airport transfers! From the airport, you will be taking a van for around 20 minutes, then you\'ll be transferred to a banca/boat for a 25 minute ride to the resort. Upon arrival, you\'ll be greeted by a band that plays their "welcome, welcome" song and in our case, we were met by Maria (awesome gal!) who introduced the group to the resort facilities and checks you in at the bar.I booked a deluxe room, which is actually a duplex with 2 adjoining rooms, ideal
for families, which accommodates 4 to a room.Rooms are clean and bed is comfortable.Potable water is provided upon check in , but is chargeable thereafter.Don\ 't worry, ...FULL REVIEW...',
 "Stayed with my wife and 2 children, 10y and 13y. ...FULL REVIEW...",
 'Beginning at now been in Coron for a couple of   ...FULL REVIEW...',
 'This was the most beautiful and relaxing place   ...FULL REVIEW...',
 'We spent 2 nights at El rio. It was incredible,  ...FULL REVIEW... ']
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. It all depends on what happens when you hit "Read More", i.e. where the actual data *is*.

There are usually two possibilities (not mutually exclusive):

- the data lies in the same page, hidden, and the "read more" is e.g. a label for a hidden checkbox that, when selected, hides the "read more" span and makes the rest of the text appear. This way the page displayed is smaller and more readable, yet it is all loaded within the same call. In that case you just need to find a suitable selector (could be for example `#someotherselector+input[type=checkbox] ~ div.moreText` or something like that).
- the data *is not there*, it will be loaded via AJAX after some time, remaining hidden, or only when you click on the "read more", to be displayed then. This allows keeping a small page that loads quickly and yet contains lots of items that would load slowly, loading them in background or on demand. In this case you need to inspect the actual AJAX call (it usually carries along an id or a data-value held in the 'Load More...' element: `<span class="loadMore" data-text-id="x19834">Read more...</span>`) and issue the same call with the appropriate headers:

  resp2 = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com.ph/whatever/api/is/used?id=' + element.attr('data-text-id'))

Without knowing how the data is retrieved and where the relevant elements (e.g. the name and content of the id-carrying attribute, etc.) are, it is not possible to give an answer that will work every time.

You might be interested in [doing this the right way](https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/), also. The data you're scraping is protected by copyright, and TripAdvisor might change things enough that you'll have problems maintaining the scraper.