# How to extract text from POPUP window

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Python Scrapy to parse some restaurants on tripadvisor. There is a popup window activated on click on the button "View all details" and containing relevant information. Traffic analysis says that nothing is called on click. However, if I search for the text inside the window in the webpage I can find one element (see it below in the screenshot), but I don't know what to do with it and how to extract text.
[image: Element find in the page's source]

P.s. I have managed to get the window's content with selenium, but I really want to do it only with Scrapy.

Thanks in advance for help!
A link for example [Link](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187323-d8025081-Reviews-Happies-Berlin.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution from this question: [Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286609/scraping-hidden-data-window-web-context-preferably-with-scrapy)

Here's an example of code for transforming scrapy's response to json

```
    # get html text
    resp_text = response.text

    # Html to json
    data = re.search(r'window\.__WEB_CONTEXT__=(.*?});', resp_text).group(1)
    data = data.replace('pageManifest', '"pageManifest"')
    data = json.loads(data)
```